# How can I get the version of the current running instance on Google App Engine nodejs?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've deployed my node application on GAE (Google App Engine) flex environment. I would like to know the created app version. After the deployement succeeds, gcloud just shows the previous version that was stopped to run the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be shown at the start of your deploy output, when you are asked for a `yes` confirmation:

```
You are about to deploy the following services:
 - project-id/default/20170425t160124 (from [path/app.yaml])
     Deploying to URL: [https://project-id.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y
```

You can also open the console, go `App Engine -> Versions` and sort by date.